# Import data from Excel to a combobox in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to add values from an Excel sheet column into a combo box in a user form that I created in a Word documnet using VBA.

If it was just a combobox in excel user form, then all I needed to write is :

```
Range("A1").Select
Do Until Selection.Value = Empty
    ComboBox1.AddItem Selection.Value
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

How can I do the same thing when I use a user form in Word and want data from an external Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that will allow you to open the excel file and browse the range you need. It was made for a dropdown but is similar:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestDropDownFromExcel()

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCC As ContentControl

    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("...")  'Location of your file
    If xlBook Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)

    'Empty the list of items in the dropdown
    oCC.DropdownListEntries.Clear

    'Populate your items here


    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlSheet = Nothing    
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

You need to include a reference to Excel: First you need to set a reference (Menu: Tools->References) to the Microsoft Excel Object Library then you can access all Excel Objects ([How to refer to Excel objects in Access VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729195/how-to-refer-to-excel-objects-in-access-vba))

See also here the sample: [Populate Word Combobox with Excel data through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861914/populate-word-combobox-with-excel-data-through-vba)