# How can I use vba to export data from an MS Access form to MS Word drop-down content control

Tags: vba, ms-access, contentcontrol, export-to-word

I'm using vba in an MS Access form to insert data from Access into MS Word content controls.  The code works for text fields, date fields and checkbox fields.  But I'm having trouble inserting data into the drop-down field.  My drop-down list properties in MS Word uses a "display name" and value to store the data (e.g. Display Name=Adirondack and Value=1, Display Name=Buffalo and Value=2).  Here is the code that works along with the error message that results from attempting to insert into a drop-down list. Your help will be much appreciated!

```
Private Sub Command179_Click()
' subroutine for exporting referral data from MS Access table to MS Word form content controls
Dim CC As ContentControl
Dim objLE As ContentControlListEntry
Dim fc As Field
Dim ccInfo As String
Dim Female As String

Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim strDocName As String
Dim blnQuitWord As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

strPath = "C:\Users\AlbanyHiker\Documents\Custom Office Templates\INTAKE FORM\INTAKE BLANK FORM.docm"
strDocName = strPath
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
appWord.Visible = True

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strDocName)

 If IsNull(Me!ref_referral_dt) Then
    MsgBox "REFERRAL DATE IS MISSING, COMPLETE FORM BEFORE EXPORT"
    Me!ref_referral_dt = #1/1/9999#
    End If

For Each CC In doc.ContentControls
        ccInfo = "<> ID= " & CC.ID & " Title = " & CC.Title & " tag = " & CC.Tag & " Text = " & CC.Range.Text & vbCrLf

        Debug.Print ccInfo
        Select Case CC.Tag:

            Case "frm_referral_dt"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_referral_dt

            Case "frm_referral_number"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_referral_number

            Case "frm_part_name_first"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_name_first

            Case "frm_part_name_last"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_name_last

            Case "frm_part_address1"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_address1

            Case "frm_part_address2"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_address2

            Case "frm_mailing_current"
                If Me!ref_mailing_current = "-1" Then CC.Checked = True

            Case "frm_part_city"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_city

            Case "frm_part_zip"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_zip

            Case "frm_part_telephone"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_telephone

' Next case statement throws the following error message
' 6124: you are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected
             Case "frm_part_region"
                CC.Range.Text = Me!ref_part_region

        End Select
Next

MsgBox "INTAKE Report Data Was Successfully Exported, Remember to Save the Word-Fillable File Using a Different Name"

Cleanup:
    'do something here to cleanup stuff
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:

Select Case Err.Number
Case -2147022986, 429
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    blnQuitWord = True
    Resume Next

Case -2147352571
    MsgBox "There is a Type Mismatch Error indicating that a date may have been mistyped" _
    & " No data imported.  PLEASE CHECK DATA ENTRY ON ALL DATES ", vbOKOnly, _
    " Please check the date entries on the form"


 Case 5121, 5174
    MsgBox "You must select a valid Word Document. " _
    & " No data was imported.", vbOKOnly, _
    " Document Not Found"

Case 5491
    MsgBox "The document you selected does not" _
    & " contain the required form fields." _
    & " No data exported.", vbOKOnly, _
    " Fields Not Found"

Case Else
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description

End Select
GoTo Cleanup

ExitSubError:
    Set rs = Nothing
    '..and set it to nothing
    MsgBox "Export failed, correct problems and export again"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: go look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861914/populate-word-combobox-with-excel-data-through-vba

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to export the stored value.  The code you suggested edits the list of drop-down values.  The Microsoft developer site also has detailed examples for changing the drop-down values.